# apache Redirect from public to internally

Tags: apache, tomcat, https, redirect, http-redirect

`https://domain.com/jaspersoft-pro` this is my correct url

Can i give this URL to client `https://domain.com/reporting` and can redirect to the below url internally `https://domain.com/jaspersoft-pro`

Is it possible to do the changes . App server is tomcat .

Comment: URL Https://domain.com/jaspersoft-pro to Https://domain.com/reporting